# Unable to Clone/Pull Git Repository on Linux Server

Tags: linux, git, git-clone

I am trying to clone a git repository with URL: `http://user@serverIP:port/RepositoryName` on a Linux server and this is the output:

```
Cloning into 'RepositoryName'...

fatal: unable to access 'http://user@serverIP:port/RepositoryName/': couldn't connect to host
```

The same error also appears when I try to pull from the repository,
while it worked properly and cloned the repository on my windows machine.

Does anyone have an idea about the problem?

Comment: do you have a connection to the server? Have you pinged it?

Comment: You really running git on http for your clients?

Comment: Do you have a proxy set on your Windows machine ?

Comment: @godot yes i did and it pinged successfully

Comment: When you write `serverIP` do you mean an IP address (i.e. dotted numbers) or do you mean a hostname? And if you do mean a hostname, perhaps you need to specify a fully qualified domain name. Another thing to try is cutting and pasting into your browser on the same PC and see if it works there. If not, it's not a git problem _per se_.